# Using Selenium, how do I read content in JQuery-based page when JQuery UI seems to make content of web elements 'un readable'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I'm working on JQuery wizard-type application.    It is a CRUD app and when I want to 'edit' one of the objects in the app, the wizard is launched with all the pages of the wizard populated with the entered data.

I was about to start the task of identifying the elements on the pages using Firebug/Firepath and discovered to my horror that although the text was visible in the element I that I located successfully with XPATH locator, there was no text in the HTML.

Here is the type of locator //div[@class='stepContainer']//td[@class='DataTD']//input[@id='myElementId’], inspection in the DOM and getting my dirty with the Firebug console and attempting get innerHTML all return empty.

I'm not sure what the developers are doing here to get this to occur but it puts my automation efforts in jeopardy but there has to be a way.

I'm relatively new to JQuery but have some good experience with Selenium.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that a textbox? Did you try to get attribute 'value' yet?

Comment: Indeed it is and sure enough that is what I needed to do.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you accept my answer so we can close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get text inside a textbox, you have to get attribute "value". See Java code below:

```
WebElement txtbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='stepContainer']//td[@class='DataTD']//input[@id='myElementId']"));
string text = txtbox.getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
String OutText=Driver.findElement(By.Id("myElementId")).getText();
```

Comment: Yeah  I tried that and it didnt work.  Instead I had to use a getValue()